# Attributes in Ruby Class are always set to null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attr-accessor

I'm trying to learn Ruby and rails, and have decided to follow Michael Hartl's tutorial. In lesson 6, which is when you create the user's database, I went back to review/modify and now whenever I try to initialize a new instance of the User class, all attributes are set to null.

Here is the User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :name, :email
  email_regex = /[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i   #makes sure the email follows a certain pattern.

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => true
end
```

In the rails console, I'll type in

User.new(:name => "master", :email => "dude@mail.com")

and the result will return only nil for all attriubtes. It should be returning the values I initialized with it. Is there something wrong with my User.rb file to not allow the attributes to initialize? I feel like this should be an easy fix, but I'm very new to ruby and rails.

Note: My version of rails is 4.1.1, ruby is 1.9.3

Comment: Can you show us the rest of that code you try in the console? eg show us how you are accessing the attributes that are null

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're mixing and matching Ruby and Rails in a way that doesn't work. You can't use `attr_accessor` with fields that have the same name as your ActiveRecord fields, or they stomp on each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take away the attr_accessor method. Attr_accessor does the following in ruby,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

....
....

def name
  @name
end 

def name=(args)
  @name = args
end
```

and validates does the following:

```
def name
  # validation method here
end
```

Comment: don't I want it to do that though? I thought ttr_accessor was a shortcut to make getters and setters, which is what you just typed there?

Comment: yes, and that's not what you want. Rails defines its own for model attributes, and you're overwriting them.

Comment: that worked. wish I could vote you up, but apparently this already has an answer

Comment: No problem man appreciate it. And your first comment was totally right it is a shortcut for getters and setters, the problem is that validates overwrites them ( or they overwrite it, precedence for same named methods is typically set vertically) by defining a method with the same name. No worries, you won't need the getters and setters, ActiveRecord will handle it for you!